# Create a List with a foreach loop (empty object)

Tags: c#, object, model

I have this code to create a list from a foreach loop from `membershipuser`..

```
public List<UsersModels> _users;
MembershipUserCollection iduser = Membership.GetAllUsers();
foreach (MembershipUser member in iduser)
{

      UsersModels usmodel = new UsersModels();
      usmodel.Username = member.UserName;
      usmodel.Email = member.Email;
      usmodel.LastLoginDate = member.LastLoginDate;
      usmodel.LastActivityDate = member.LastActivityDate;
      _users.Add(usmodel); // BREAKPOINT

}
```

When I put a breakpoint at the bottom, I can see all the data is OK, but after adding the object (another object to the list) it tells:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the breakpoint showing that the data apparently is OK

http://i.imgbox.com/aafDt7MJ.png

Can someone tell me what can be wrong? I dont understand why the usmodel object has its data apparently OK, but cannot add it to the list showing the error above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not initialized the _users variable.  Therefore, _users.Add() is throwing an error

Comment: Thanks Mike, i have spend much time to try to fix it, and i havent see where is wrong..Thanks again!